# Loop over image filenames and split them

Tags: python, loops, split, filenames

I'm trying to slice a bunch of images from a directory. Try to loop over them, but I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '45678.png'`

Actually, that's the name of one of the files. This is my code:

```
import image_slicer
import os

indir = '/Users/data/h3'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith('.png'):
            image_slicer.slice(file, 4)
```

Dir is ok, I don't get why cannot find the file, when actually finds it as per the error message

Comment: You should add the [python] tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the filename when you open it with `slice()`.

Try `image_slicer.slice(os.path.join(dirpath, name), 4)`